# Mobile Jquery slider is not showing properly

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an ios app using phonegap. I have used following code for implementing a slider in my app

```
<form>
    <label for="slider">Product quality:</label>
    <input type="number" data-type="range" name="slider" id="slider-1" value="0" min="0" max="100"/>
 </form>
```

But its not displaying the slider properly. Please help me!!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if you use incompatible versions of jQuery Mobile js file and css file. For example 1.3.1 js and 1.2.1 css file.

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/31/

Make sure you are using correct jQuery Mobile files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```